# Apostrophe generates incorrect urls to css files

Tags: apostrophe-cms

When running my app on my Windows 8 machine, incorrect urls are emitted for css files only (.js file urls render correctly, only css files look to have the issue). The same app run on OSX works. The Request URL being sent to the browser in Windows is:
http://localhost:3000/css/..modulesmy-apostrophe-pages%0Css%0Bootstrap.css

Is there an encoding setting that needs to be changed in Windows? This url renders the file: 
http://localhost:3000//modules/my-apostrophe-pages/Css/Bootstrap.css

Thanks